# How does google dynamically count on its space for gmail?

Tags: gmail, google

When we look at Gmail login page, we can see the space counting dynamically. What does it represent - does it mean that Google is dynamically increasing it's server space?

What happens in the back end while the Gmail space gets dynamically increased?

[image]

Comment: It's just a marketing gimmick. They increase the amount of space available to you on a regularly basis. They just use JavaScript to count up from a particular number. They're not actually dynamically increasing the amount of storage available to you in real time.

Comment: Does anybody know if that counter is still displayed on a google page somewhere? Last time I looked at it I remember it being difficult to find and now I can't find it at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Al [mentioned](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/42288/how-does-google-dynamically-count-on-its-space-for-gmail#comment33439_42288), it's just a gimmick plus some JavaScript trickery that shows the 'real-time' increase - in practice, the amount is a fixed space which gets increased at regular intervals.

This [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4531169/92837) explains how the JS bit works

> This is the code in charge of it. Looks like it is based on a time
>   computation being mapped to a number of Bytes.
>
> ```
> function updateQuota() {
>   if (!quota_elem) {
>   return;
>   }
>   var now = (new Date()).getTime();
>   var i;
>   for (i = 0; i < CP.length; i++) {
>     if (now < CP[i][0]) {
>       break;
>     }
>   }
>   if (i == 0) {
>     setTimeout(updateQuota, 1000); 
>   } else if (i == CP.length) {
>     quota_elem.innerHTML = CP[i - 1][3];
>   } else {
>     var ts = CP[i - 1][0];
>     var bs = CP[i - 1][4];
>     quota_elem.innerHTML = format(((now-ts) / (CP[i][0]-ts) * (CP[i][5]-bs)) + bs); 
>     setTimeout(updateQuota, 1000); 
>   } 
> } 
>
> var PAD = '.000000';
> ```